# How to add Location Header in response body on go-restful plugin

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, openapi-generator, go-restful

I cannot add documentation on response header and generate this schema by using [go-restful](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful) :

I want response body on schema to be like this:

```
"responses": {
  "302": {
    "description": "Found. Redirected to login page with either request_id or error.",
    "headers": {
      "Location": {
        "description": "The Location header",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried all the API and cannot get the expected result.
for generating client code with [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger)